# How to Get All Meta_Keys and Meta_Values Into Their Own Rows

Tags: sql

My query is used to get data about products that are downloadable, belong to a category called 'test-category', and where the current user has permission to download them.

I’ve spent some time figuring out how to return all the meta_keys and meta_fields, however, I was only able to return them all into a single row.

**My current goal** is to get all the `meta_keys` and `meta_values` into their own rows.

**So, instead of (current results):**

```
meta_keys > key1, key2, key3, key4, key5
meta_values > value1, value2, value3, value4, value5
```

**it should be:**

```
key1 > value1 
key2 > value2 
key3 > value3 
key4 > value4 
key5 > value5
```

**Current SQL query:**

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT {prefix}postmeta_custom.meta_key) AS meta_keys, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT {prefix}postmeta_custom.meta_value) AS meta_values
FROM {prefix}posts
INNER JOIN {prefix}postmeta ON {prefix}posts.ID = {prefix}postmeta.post_id
INNER JOIN {prefix}term_relationships ON {prefix}posts.ID = {prefix}term_relationships.object_id
INNER JOIN {prefix}term_taxonomy ON {prefix}term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = {prefix}term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN {prefix}terms ON {prefix}term_taxonomy.term_id = {prefix}terms.term_id
INNER JOIN {prefix}woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions ON {prefix}posts.ID = {prefix}woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions.product_id
INNER JOIN {prefix}postmeta AS {prefix}postmeta_image ON {prefix}posts.ID = {prefix}postmeta_image.post_id
INNER JOIN {prefix}posts AS {prefix}posts_image ON {prefix}postmeta_image.meta_value = {prefix}posts_image.ID
INNER JOIN {prefix}postmeta AS {prefix}postmeta_custom ON {prefix}posts.ID = {prefix}postmeta_custom.post_id
WHERE {prefix}posts.post_type = 'product'
AND {prefix}posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND {prefix}postmeta.meta_key = '_downloadable'
AND {prefix}postmeta.meta_value = 'yes'
AND {prefix}term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
AND {prefix}terms.slug = 'test-category'
AND {prefix}woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions.user_id = %current_user_id%
AND {prefix}postmeta_image.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
GROUP BY {prefix}posts.ID
```

Comment: Just don’t use GROUP BY/GROUP_CONCAT?